# Is it possible to show multi-level threads in Mail.app?

Tags: email, mail.app

I like the threaded view for mail.app, but it only groups the messages per thread. In other words, there's only two levels: the original messages, and all the replies that came after that.

Is it possible (perhaps via plugin?) to show a multi-level view of the e-mail thread in mail.app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm sorry; that's not possible.

Answer (score 2):

As an alternative to the lack of Mail features (good threading being one of those), you can try any of the following, which I’m sure you already know:

- [Postbox](http://www.postbox-inc.com/): Lots of features, multiplatform, not free.
- [Thunderbird](http://www.mozillamessaging.com/en-US/thunderbird/): Very decent mail client, free and also multiplatform.
- [Mailplane](http://mailplaneapp.com/): If you like Gmail but don’t want to lose OS X features, Mailplane is a very decent alternative combining the best of gmail with a respectable OS X integration.
- [Sparrow](http://sparrowmailapp.com/): A new alternative (only for gmail) that is growing in popularity for its ease of use and iPad-like interface. Although it only works for gmail, the plan is to expand it. Still very beta. Still free. Worth to follow around and check every now and then.
- There may be others but these are the most known/used (excluding Mail.app of course). Eudora is also popular, but I believe it’s a little bit outdated.